# Bosch router Collet shafts stuck

Tags: woodworking, routers

I need to put on a new wood router Collet for smaller bit. I am unable to remove the old collet fully. The black nut comes off easily and is upside down in the image. The shaft inside the collet nut is not coming off.

This is the POF 1400 ACE. My 6mm router bit is not going in and the 0.25" is being too loose. This is why I need to remove this collet fully. The box for this router came with 2 more collets and each has a silver color shift inside the black collet nut.

[image]

Comment: The collet usually has a flared tip.  Can you fit some end nippers in the hole to pull the collet out by its flared tip?  (Might have to remove the base plate if you can't fit the nippers in the hole.)

Comment: I used pliers and after a few attempts, was able to pull the thing out. All the confusion led to 2.5h of wasted time. I had earlier tried to use loose pliers and screw driver to bring this thing out but it would not come out.